# Windows App only connects to REST Api when Appmanifest changes

Tags: c#, windows, rest, vagrant, uwp

### Problem Description

My C# Windows App can only connect to my local Testserver´s Rest Api (on Virtualbox) when I change random Stuff on the appxmanifest file. It doesn't matter at all what changes (I tried e.g. checking or unchecking landscape), the build after the manifest change will be able to connect, the build after that will not. (And local network needs to be checked in the Capabilities)
With my Online-hosted Server it works all the time with the same Code. (Im just changing the baseuri, user and pw then)

### The Error Message

Doesn't say a lot, just cant connect to the server if I don't change the manifest before clicking on debug.[image: cant connect]

### Virtualbox Testserver

I used this [Setup](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/shopware-vagrant) to create the Testserver. (Vagrant for Shopware)
[image]

### My Code for httpClient (using Windows.Web)

I don't think its relevant to the problem but im using the following codesnippet to connect to the Rest Api:

```
    public async Task<string> GET(Uri uri)
    {
        Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter =
            new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.AllowUI = false;

        // Set credentials that will be sent to the server.
        filter.ServerCredential =
            new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(
                uri.ToString(),
                Username,
                Password);

        client = new HttpClient(filter);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return res;
    }
```

Do I need to change something in the Visual Studio Settings or in Virtualbox?
Can I change something in Virtualbox so I don't need to check "local network" in the appxmanifest Capabilities?

Comment: I'm not  familiar with VirtualBox, but as long as it's a local server, you need to have the `Private Network(Client&Server)` Capability checked. And please try ping your local server.

Comment: Capability is checked. When I ping the Server it works (192.168.33.10), when I ping the Website it doesn't (192.168.33.10/shopware/) @ElvisXia-MSFT